# How to do paging and sorting in reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs

> I need the react-material  so that we can do the sorting and paging in
>   our reactjs application.I have added the table to display the data as
>   :-

```
<Table height={this.state.height}   fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}   fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}  selectable={this.state.selectable}   multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable} >
      <TableHeader  displaySelectAll={this.state.showCheckboxes} adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes} enableSelectAll={this.state.enableSelectAll} >
        <TableRow>
             <TableHeaderColumn colSpan="3" tooltip="Super Header" >
                <h5 className="mgn20">Employee Details</h5>
             </TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="The ID">ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="The Name">Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="The Status">Status</TableHeaderColumn>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody  displayRowCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}   deselectOnClickaway={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}   showRowHover={this.state.showRowHover}  stripedRows={this.state.stripedRows}>
        {tableData.map( (row, index) => (
          <TableRow key={index} selected={row.selected}>
            <TableRowColumn>{index}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.name}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{row.status}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
              ))}
    </TableBody>
      <TableFooter adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}>

      </TableFooter>
</Table>
```

> Now in  I want **pagination** and also in header column
>   of table we need the **sorting**. So in the reactjs,How can I add
>   these two functionality?

Comment: You can use http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/